# Duplicated log on single request with a minus sign at the end

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a setup where one nginx does reverse proxy to a second one.

I observed in my logs, that one nginx sees two request but the second one sees just one of them. I also observed that the browser is just sending one request, so the duplication if exists, does not come from the client.

Here is a sample of the logs:

```
nginx_1  | 192.168.64.8 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic1.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 9402 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
proxy_1  | 192.168.64.1 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 111773 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
proxy_1  | 192.168.64.1 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 111773 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
proxy_1  | 192.168.64.1 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 25619 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36" "-"
proxy_1  | 192.168.64.1 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 25619 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1  | 192.168.64.8 - - [15/Jul/2016:11:43:32 +0000] "GET /images/mypic2.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 25619 "http://localhost/es" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
```

As you can see, proxy_1 is the nginx working as reverse proxy, and nginx_1 is the one receiving and processing the requests.

In the end of every duplicated line you can see a "-" that I don't know what it means. I suspect is doing some sort of rewriting I'm not aware of but don't understand how it happens.

Could you give me some clue about what is going on here?

Here I also provide the server config:

```
access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stdout;

server {
    listen 7000;
    listen 80;

    client_max_body_size 24M;
    server_name *.rareconnect.org;

    include /etc/nginx/params/gzip_on;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/params/proxy_pass_local_rareconnect_org_8000;
    }
}
```

This is on top of the standard configuration of nginx:1.9.5 as appears in the official docker registry.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are few records `access_log`. Can you check `nginx.conf` as well?

Comment: Just added it on the main message

Comment: Ok, there are two `access_log` records.
You can remove `access_log /dev/stdout;` and try again. Should work fine